# What is the difference between SN74HCxxN and SN74HCxxAN parts?

Tags: components, texas-instruments

I'm trying to compare between two different parts on Digikey: the [SN74HC148N](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74HC148N/376979) and the [SN74HC148AN](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74HC148AN/1902714). Both pages link to the same [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scls109h/scls109h.pdf), which does not list anything to do with an AN suffix. What is the difference between the N and AN suffix on TI's SN74HCxx parts?

Comment: Zero search results on ti.com on SN74HC148AN. I find one scanned Chinese datasheet for SN74HC148A though.

Comment: TI has excellent support. Ask at [TI forums](https://e2e.ti.com/) or create an account and ask at [TI customer support](https://support.ti.com/csm). In my experience they usually answer within one or two days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TI's [[FAQ] What is the difference between the SN74HCxx and the SN74HCxxA?](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic-group/logic/f/logic-forum/814317/faq-what-is-the-difference-between-the-sn74hcxx-and-the-sn74hcxxa) says:

> Some of these parts were translated into Japanese and renamed to SN74HCxxA. They have their own datasheets with identical specifications to the non-A versions, and are advertised on the TI Japan website. The primary difference between the "A" and non-"A" devices is that the "A" devices have a datasheet in Japanese, and the non-"A" versions do not. There are other minor differences, namely that the "A" versions have not been updated in a very long time (since 1998) and thus are likely out of date. Some non-"A" versions have been temperature extended to support 125C, and their specifications have been adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was maybe the most directly useful line for my specific needs: "TI recommends using the SN74HCxx version of parts when presented with the choice."